# DebugView doesn't capture KdPrint output

Tags: windows, windows-10, kernel, driver

I cannot make DbgView.exe work properly on my Windows 10 64-bit v2004 Virtual Machine. The program doesn't capture any kernel message from the driver if using KdPrint, but works fine with DbgPrint. I've already tried "bcdedit /debug on", adding "Debug Print Filter" on the registry editor and rebooting, enabling verbose kernel output.
I've also tried on my host machine, same outcome.
It is a very simple driver, only to be loaded and unloaded, copied from the book Windows Kernel Programming.

This works

```
DbgPrint("Driver initialized.\n");
```

This doesn't

```
KdPrint(("Driver initialized.\n"));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Jump to `KdPrint` and you will see a preprocessing magic:

```
#if DBG 

#define KdPrint(_x_) DbgPrint _x_
#define KdPrintEx(_x_) DbgPrintEx _x_ 
#define vKdPrintEx(_x_) vDbgPrintEx _x_
#define vKdPrintExWithPrefix(_x_) vDbgPrintExWithPrefix _x_
#define KdBreakPoint() DbgBreakPoint() 

#define KdBreakPointWithStatus(s) DbgBreakPointWithStatus(s)

#else 

#define KdPrint(_x_)
#define KdPrintEx(_x_) 
#define vKdPrintEx(_x_)
#define vKdPrintExWithPrefix(_x_)
#define KdBreakPoint() 

#define KdBreakPointWithStatus(s)

#endif // DBG wudfwdm
```

This means that if you are compiling with *Release* configuration (`DBG` macro will not be defined), nothing will happen to `KdPrint`.

So it's not a DbgView problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even with debug compiled drivers, dbgView 4.90 on winPE (dbgview64.exe) does not print KdPrint unless you click both Capture, Capture Kernel, and Capture, Enable Verbose Kernel Output.