# Windows kernel driver cannot print to DebugView

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf

I have just completed the installation of [Hello World Windows Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver), the installation is success.

The code in this basically printing a line:

```
KdPrintEx(( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n" ));
```

For seeing this I have downloaded the [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), but the expected `"KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry"` is not getting print in this.

I am running DebugView as administrator in Windows-8.1.
I have checked, that it has made a device under the device manager named `"KMDFHelloWorld Device"`.

[image]
What could be the probable reason that it is not getting print? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable the following 4 options:

[image]

And check if your driver is compiled with Debug configuration. As to why, see [DebugView doesn't capture KdPrint output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270584/13433323).

Comment: It works for me,Thanks A ton :).One more thing is it the expected behavior that it form a device under the device manager ?

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia I haven't noticed that. Could you post a screenshot to explain it?

Comment: Edit question with screenshot

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia I'm not sure about this, I guess it might be related to the `.inf` file, if you are still curious you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and wait for someone to answer it.